# WPF hwnd-adorner is not working .net 6 WPF application

Tags: wpf

I am trying to use migrate one of our application from .Net Framework 4.8 to .Net6, after migration Hwnd Adnore is not working. Below the hwnd-adorner we used in the application. Same code is working fine in the .Net Framework 4.8, but it is not working properly in the .Net6. Please share if any have the solution.

https://github.com/michaelsutton/hwnd-adorner

Solution for the  hwnd-adorner in .net6 WPF application